# NFSv4 which "domain" to put in idmapd.conf?

Tags: centos, files, configuration, nfs

I'm using NFSv4 but suddenly when the NFS Server got rebooted, all the files on the Clients are having `nobody` ownerships after the Server is booted and started its whatever services again.

Then I found some solutions to set the `Domain=_____` in the `idmapd.conf` file.

- But what am I suppose to put there (in both Server and Clients)?
- I only have IP addresses.

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netos/article.php/3644471/Implement-NFSv4-Domains-and-Authentication.htm as well as this one:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto

Comment: Also here's a CentOS specific article for domain + NFSv4 http://blog.laimbock.com/2009/05/21/nfsv4-on-centos-53-and-fedora-11/

Comment: there, it is mentioned `change Domain to <your.fully.qualified.domain.name>`. My question here is, what to add for `fqdn` there?

Answer (score 3):

If you actually have a valid, globally-unique domain name reserved to you, that is of course a great choice.

But more important than the actual value of the NFS4 domain setting is probably that the *same* domain setting is used both in the NFS4 server and all its clients. If the domains are different, the server will treat all client users as `nobody`.